# How to interpret the expression $e^{O(x)}=e^{O(x^2)}\ \ \ \ \ (x\to \infty)$?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, asymptotics

My question is about the meaning of the expression

$$e^{O(x)}=e^{O(x^2)}\ \ \ \ \  (x\to \infty)\tag{1}$$

which I found in the Introduction chapter of the book *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis* by N.G. de Bruijn.

I am trying to learn about Big-O notation as it is used in mathematics. I want to be very meticulous about each step of the way. I hope any errors below, no matter how small or philosophical, might be pointed out.

Let $f$ be a function such that $$f(x)=O(x)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)$$

This means that there are numbers $a$ and $A$ such that

$$|f(x)|\leq A|x|$$

for all $x$ such that $a<x<\infty$.

Furthermore, there is some number $b$ (possibly equal to $a$) such that

$$|f(x)|\leq A|x|<A|x^2|$$

for all $x$ such that $b<x<\infty$.

Thus

$$f(x)=O(x^2)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)$$

Now let $g$ be a function such that

$$g(x)=O(x^2)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)$$

Then $$f(x)=O(g(x))\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)\tag{2}$$

which means there are numbers $c$ and $C$ such that

$$|f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|$$

for all $x$ such that $c<x<\infty$.

Thus

$$e^{|f(x)|}\leq e^{C|g(x)|}\tag{3}$$

In summary, for any two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)=O(x)$ and $g(x)=O(x^2)$, we have that there is some constant $C$ such that $e^{|f(x)|}\leq e^{C|g(x)|}$.

**Is this the correct intepretation, technically and intuitively, of $(1)$?**

Comment: $\{ e^{f(n)} : f \in O(n) \}$ and $\{ e^{f(n)} : f \in O(n^2) \}$

Comment: Okay, so $e^{O(x)}$ represents the set of functions $\{ e^{f(n)}:f\in O(n) \}$. Likewise $e^{O(x^2)}$ represents the set of functions $\{ e^{f(n)}:f\in O(n^2) \}$. In other words, expressions such as $e^{O(x)}$ and $e^{O(x^2)}$ represent "classes of functions" (in the words of the book I am reading). As I've read further along, it seems that the expression $e^{O(x)}=e^{O(x^2)}$ means that the set of functions on the left is contained in the set of functions on the right. Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

I do think the notation often used to express the relative growth of functions is tortured. I mean, try parsing out the statement $e^{O(x)}=e^{O(x^2)}$. Do $e^{O(x)}$ and $e^{O(x^2)}$ denote functions or sets. Either way the "$=$" is problematic. If these denote sets say, then there are functions in $e^{O(x^2)}$ that are not in $e^{O(x)}$, so $e^{O(x)}$ is not the same set as $e^{O(x^2)}$, the "$=$" notwithstanding. But I digress.

We now show the following claim:

**Claim 1:** *Let $f$ be a real-valued function on the positive real line. If $f$ is $e^{O(x)}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$, then $f$ is $e^{O(x^2)}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.*

Proof:

1. Iff $f$ as above is $e^{O(x)}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$, then by definition there is a real number $x_0$ and a real-valued function $r(x)$ on the positive reals such that both $r(x)$ is $O(x)$ and $f \le e^{r(x)}$.
2. But clearly, if $r(x)$ is $O(x)$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$, then $r(x)$ is $O(x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.
3. So then iff $f$ above is $e^{O(x)}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$, then there is a real number $x_0$ and a real-valued function $r(x)$ on the positive reals such that both $r(x)$ is $O(x^2)$ and $f \le e^{r(x)}$.
4. But then from 3. it follows by definition that $f$ is $e^{O(x^2)}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

And so Claim 1 follows. ■

The converse of Claim 1 is NOT true however, looking at Step 2 above, not every function that is $O(x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$, is also $O(x)$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Yes, one wonders why the source text didn't use $\subseteq$ or $\subset$ instead of $=$.

Comment: Well, people do tend to write too often something like, say, $f(x)=O(x)=O(x^2)$. And I get it, 'everyone knows what they mean', and so they've made peace w that abuse of notation.

Comment: @BrianTung I suppose it is similar to the convention in calculus of writing say $\int 4x^3dx = x^4+C$, instead of the correct $\int_a^x 4t^3dt = x^4+C$ where of course $C$ depends on $a$]. Tortured notation indeed but still accepted...

Comment: I feel like the abuses are worse with big-$O$ notation. I'm not sure I can articulate why, but it feels worse.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression in the original question

$$f(x)=O(g(x))\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)\tag{2}$$

is not true.

As an example, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1$, then we have

$$f(x)=O(x)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)$$

$$g(x)=O(x^2)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)$$

but $(2)$ is not true.

It appears this invalidates the interpretation given of $(1)$ in the original question.

I'd like to give my updated interpretation, in light of Mike's answer.

> Given any function $f$ such that $f(x)=O(x)\ (x\to \infty)$, we have that the function $e^{f(x)}$ is $e^{O(x^2)}\ (x\to\infty)$, which means that there are numbers $a$ and $A$ such that for $a<x<\infty$ we have $e^{f(x)}\leq e^{A|x^2|}$.

A slightly different way of saying this (as Mike did in his answer) is not in terms of $|x^2|$ but in terms of some function that is $O(x^2)$.

> Given any function $f$ such that $f(x)=O(x)\ (x\to \infty)$, we have that the function $e^{f(x)}$ is $e^{O(x^2)}\ (x\to \infty)$, which means that there is some number $a$ and some function $r(x)$ such that $r(x)=O(x^2)$ and for $a<x<\infty$ we have $e^{f(x)}\leq e^{r(x)}$.
>
> Since $r(x)=O(x^2)\ (x\to \infty)$ means that there is some $A$ such that $|r(x)|\leq A|x^2|$ then we have that for any $x$ such that $a<x<\infty$,
> $$e^{f(x)}\leq e^{r(x)}\leq e^{A|x^2|}$$

Thus, both ways of saying what $(1)$ means are saying the same thing.